# MudRadioGroup not toggling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, mudblazor

My razor page has radiogroup like

```
<MudRadioGroup T="string" SelectedOption="@selectedName" SelectedOptionChanged="OnSelectedOptionChanged">
                <MudRadio Option="@("Adam")" Color="Color.Primary">Index</MudRadio>
                <MudRadio Option="@("Greg")" Color="Color.Primary">Regex</MudRadio>
 </MudRadioGroup>
 @if (_isOk)
 {
      <MudTextField Value="@prop1" Label="txt1" />
      <MudTextField Value="@prop2" Label="txt2" />
  }
  else
  {
      <MudTextField Value="prop3" Label="txt3" />
  }
```

In code behind i bind radio group like below

```
 private string selectedName = string.Empty;
 private bool _isOk;
 protected override void OnInitialized()
 {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ScanRule.RegexRule))
    {
        selectedName = "Adam";
        _isOk= true;
    }
    else
    {
        selectedName = "Greg";
        _isOk= false;
    }
  }

 private void OnSelectedOptionChanged(string selectedOption)
 {
    _isOk= selectedOption == "Adam";
 }
```

If i try to change option button then nothing happens. When i set debug point inside OnselectedOptionChanged method and try to change option buttons then it comes inside it twice which is wrong i think as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `SelectedOption` and `SelectedOptionChanged`.

Then the handler method that you assign to `SelectedOptionChanged` i.e. *OnSelectedOptionChanged* will need to also handle changing of the value for the variable that you declare on `SelectedOption` i.e. *selectedName*

```cs
private void OnSelectedOptionChanged(string selectedOption)
 {
    selectedName= selectedOption;
    _isOk= selectedName== "Adam";
 }
```

This is done automatically if you use the @bind directive `@bind-SelectedOption="selectedName"`.

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckGRlvuvKHTBcqQc)

Comment: didnt quite understand. How should mudradio group should look?

Comment: No change anywhere else. I've attached a snippet.

Comment: i saw but i dont see any difference with my code so why it doesnt toggle in my scenario?

Comment: ah ok got it. thanks

Comment: Because that is how [Blazor data binding](https://blazor-university.com/components/two-way-binding/) works. The MudRadioGroup relies on the value for `SelectedOption`.